# Android Keyhash for Facebook issues

Tags: android, facebook, certificate, facebook-android-sdk, keystroke

I along with my friend are developing a App which has login with Facebook. We both generated our own key hash and gave it while generating the AppId.

The problem is I can sign in through Facebook but my friend cannot. The login works perfectly for me but my friend is unable to login.I use Windows and my friends uses a Mac.

Does Facebook take only one key hash?
What may be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

Please check in the App Settings (in App Dashboard), that `Sandbox Mode` is **disabled**

`Keyhash` is not the issue if it is working for one user.

Comment: The sand box is disabled in the app.

Comment: Can you please tell me what may be problem?

Comment: We are getting this problem only if we are already having Facebook app on our mobile